# Update SQL database using AJAX

Tags: php, sql, ajax

I have a code that I've copied from a website but I can't figure out how to use it properly:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
$field = $_POST['db_field'];
$value = $_POST['db_value'];
$link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("login", $link);
mysql_query("UPDATE users SET $field='$value' WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'"", $link);
mysql_close($link);
}
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function performAjaxSubmission() {
$.ajax({
url: 'editprofile.php',
method: 'POST',
data: {
action: 'save',
field: $(this).attr("db_field"), 
val: $(this).attr("db_value")
},
success: function() {
alert("success!");
}
});
return false; // <--- important, prevents the link's href (hash in this example) from executing.
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
$(".savebtn").click(performAjaxSubmission);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="gear">
<label>Primary E-Mail:</label>
<span id="pemail" class="datainfo"><?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?></span>
<a href="#" class="editlink" db_field="user_email" db_value="$_SESSION['user_email']">Edit Info</a>
<a class="savebtn">Save</a>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

My database is called "login" with a table inside of it called "users". I want to have multiple editable links (basically for an edit profile page). The current example is for editing the logged in user's e-mail "user_email" which is stored as $_SESSION data as "user_email" as well. The webpage itself is called editprofile.php

I think my issue lies with db_value -- I want this to be the value that is edited. When I click the edit button and change the value, everything seems to work fine.. When I hit save it actually prompts you saying that it saved, but there are no changes in my database.

I apologize for the elementary question, hopefully you guys can help me out.

Following the edit email link will be various other edit links such as edit address and edit phone number. An example would be:

```
<div class="gear">
<label>Primary PhoneNumber:</label>
<span id="pphone" class="datainfo"><?php echo $_SESSION['user_phone_number']; ?></span>
<a href="#" class="editlink" db_field="user_phone_number" db_value="$_SESSION['user_phone_number']">Edit Info</a>
<a class="savebtn">Save</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, You have added extra `"` end of the query.

```
 mysql_query("UPDATE users SET `$field`='$value' WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");
```

instead of

```
mysql_query(
 "UPDATE users SET $field='$value' WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'"", $link);
                                                                   ...^
```

**UPDATE:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function performAjaxSubmission() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'test.php',
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            action: 'save',
            field: $("#db_field").val(), 
            val: $("#db_value").attr()
        },
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data.success);
            }
        });
    return false; 
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $(".savebtn").click(performAjaxSubmission);
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="gear">
    <label>Primary E-Mail:</label>
    <span id="pemail" class="datainfo"><?php echo $_SESSION['user_email']; ?></span>
    <a href="#" class="editlink">Edit Info</a>

    <input type="hidden" id="db_field" value="user_email">
    <input type="hidden" id="db_value" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['user_email'];?>">

    <a class="savebtn">Save</a>
```

in test.php,

```
<?php 
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login"); 
    $message ="";
     if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { $message =  "Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error(); } 


     if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
        $field = $_POST['db_field'];
        $value = $_POST['db_value'];            
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE users SET `$field`='$value' WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'");
        mysqli_close($conn);
        $message ="Updated Sucessfuly!";
     }

     echo json_encode(array('success'=>$message));
    ?>
```

Comment: Thanks, I removed the extra " at the end of my mysql_query like you suggested, but it still doesn't save the edits to my database.

Comment: create new php file and move your php update related code along with DB connection. Use that file name in `ajax` url parameter

Comment: This is my new page, still no luck:

`<?php /* 
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","login"); 
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
 {
 echo "Connect failed: " . mysqli_connect_error();
 exit();
 } */
?> 

<?php
  if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
   $field = $_POST['db_field'];
   $value = $_POST['db_value'];
    $link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
 mysql_select_db("login", $link);
    mysql_query("UPDATE users SET $field='$value' WHERE user_id='$_SESSION[user_id]'", $link);
    mysql_close($link);
  }
?>`

Comment: Yup, that entire block of code in my previous comment is all on one page.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it still didn't work. The website loads fine, the button works fine, but my database still doesn't update. I think there's an issue with the db_value -- I understand db_field, that's the field I want to edit (ie user_email), but I have no idea what to put for the db_value as that's what I want to be updated (ie testemail@gmail.com -> testemailupdate@gmail.com)

Comment: Still no luck.. Sorry ):

Comment: It should work, if supposed not working, may be you have missed something.

Comment: Have you used my all updated code? Please check or verify my updated answer with your code!

Comment: Yes I have. For some reason my database still doesn't get updated.

Comment: copy the update query and run in your mysql query window and verify that !

Comment: I should mention that I'm using an Ajax library:
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Also I tried copying the update query and running it in the mysql query window after changing my variables to my test user and it worked properly.